# GAE yamlを書いてpythonで作ったtweet botを運用したい！

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud, google-api, yaml

GAEを使用してtweet botを運用したいのですが、使い方がよく分かりません。

**やりたい事**
指定した時間にプログラムを実行するようにしたい。
無料で運用したい。

**現状**
コードは1つのファイルにまとめてある。（ローカルでは動作確認済み）
その中にtweetするデータを収集する関数
収集したデータをtweetする関数がある。
google cloud for sdk ubuntu14.04（vagrant内で動作)インストール済み
app.yaml(GAEの設定ファイル？）、cron.yaml（時間指定に必要？）、requirements.txt(pythonのライブラリーをインストール)というのがデプロイするのに必要という事がなんとなくわかっている。

**わからない事**
yamlの書き方が分からない。
ドキュメントを見るとFlaskでの始め方が書いてあるが、それは常に実行されていて？urlにアクセスする事で動作している？多分違う解釈

年明けでいきなりすません。
エンジニアの方々の技術が必要です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAMLの書き方ということであれば以下リンク先にリファレンスがありました。

[cron.yaml リファレンス](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref?hl=ja)

Comment: ドキュメントを見るとurlにアクセスする事が引き金みたいに見えるのですがそれだとflaskなどを使用しないといけないです。関数をそのまま指定する事はできないのでしょうか？やはり使用上無理なのでしょうか？

Comment: このようなサービスではサーバーを立てるのが必須条件なのでしょうか？